# How to run an sql query inside another SQL query in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I run a SELECT query which picks an ID which I use to delete a row in another table with that ID and later delete the row of that ID in its own table?

My code so far:

```
    $sqel = "SELECT fldRadioCampID FROM tblradiocamp WHERE fldBestelID = '$urlIDbon' AND fldSpotnaam = '$urlDelSpotnaam'";
    $result = mysql_query($link, $sqel);
    
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $sqeldelreg = "DELETE FROM tblradioregio WHERE fldRadiocampRegID=" . $row['fldRadioCampID'];
        
    if (!mysql_query($sqeldelreg)) {

    echo "Error: " . $sqeldelreg . "<br>" . mysql_error($link);
    
}
    }
} else {
}   
$sqeldel = "DELETE FROM tblradiocamp WHERE fldBestelID='$urlIDbon' AND fldSpotnaam='$urlDelSpotnaam'";

    if (!mysql_query($sqeldel)) {

    echo "Error: " . $sqeldel . "<br>" . mysql_error($link);
```

Comment: You will need 3 queries.  First, a select to get the record identifier.  Then, a delete for each of the two tables.

Comment: Please delete this and start a fresh after dumping mysql_* functions and learning how to use PDO and parameter binding. Then read up on joins. Followed up join deletes

Comment: @DanBracuk , I have that, First a SELECT query wich I use to get the ID, then I run another query to find that ID in the second table and delete those rows, then a third one to delete the ID in the table itself. Isn't that correct?

Comment: It's excessive.  Once you have found the ID, you don't have to find it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can create procedure and call it once.

MYSQL

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `deleteRowById` (in urlDelSpotnaam varchar(64), in urlIDbon varchar(64) )
BEGIN
declare a int(11);
SELECT fldRadioCampID into a FROM tblradiocamp WHERE fldBestelID = urlIDbon AND fldSpotnaam = urlDelSpotnaam;
if a > 0 then
DELETE FROM tblradioregio WHERE fldRadiocampRegID=a;
DELETE FROM tblradiocamp WHERE fldRadioCampID=a;
END IF;
END
```

PHP

```
<?php

$sqel = "call deleteRowById('$urlDelSpotnaam','$urlIDbon')";
$result = mysql_query($link, $sqel);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that is what I wanted, because if a = 0, it still needs to delete the ID from the parent table.

Answer (score 0):

run this query:

```
DELETE FROM tblradioregio 
WHERE fldRadiocampRegID = (SELECT 
        fldRadioCampID 
         FROM tblradiocamp 
         WHERE fldBestelID = '$urlIDbon' AND fldSpotnaam = '$urlDelSpotnaam');
```

Note that this could also be done using a join instead of the sub-select; that's probably preferable if the subquery can return null:

```
DELETE FROM tblradioregio
    join tblradiocamp b
    on (tblradioregio.fldRadiocampRegID = b.fldRadioCampID)
    WHERE b.fldBestelID = '$urlIDbon' 
      AND b.fldSpotnaam ='$urlDelSpotnaam';
```